# Date format to change

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-loader

I need help to change the date format from (`05 May 2016 12:00 AM`) to (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) format.

Can you please help me on this?

Many thanks for your help.

I have tried below format

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2 Apr 2015 12:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY '), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM dual;
```

Thanks for the Help MTO. But i am using same format in sqlldr then getting below error.

> ora-01821 date format not recognized

```
 LAST_UPDATE DATE 'TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:LAST_UPDATE, 'DD MON YYYY HH12:MI AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')',
```

Comment: Just do it. Whats the issue? It will be (2016-05-05 00:00:00)... Whats the problem in that?

Comment: The _display_ format is controlled by the application displaying the values. A `date` value is stored without any format. Check the manual for your SQL client to see how you can change the output format

Comment: hi i have tried but getting below error..ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: `to_char(to_date(..)..)` does not make any sense. You can simply replace your expression with a string constant `'2015-04-02'`

Comment: Hmm, you writing '05 May..' and '2 Apr..' at the same post.

Comment: that is actual code i have used in my query.. thats why i posted original one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in SQL*Loader and populating a `DATE` column then you want your initial string to be converted to a date, not back to another string in another format.

If you use the [SQL operator functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226) then you only need the inner `to_date()` part, not the outer `to_char()`, and notice that the operator is enclosed in double quotes rather than single quotes:

```
LAST_UPDATE "TO_DATE(:LAST_UPDATE, 'DD MON YYYY HH12:MI AM')",
```

But there is simpler handling for [datetimes and intervals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1166), which you are sort of trying to use with the `DATE` keyword; but then you're supplying the SQL operators instead of just a format mask. You can just do:

```
LAST_UPDATE DATE 'DD MON YYYY HH12:MI AM'.
```

This assumes SQL*Loader is run in an english-language NLS_LANG environment, since it relies on the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE setting to handle the `MON` element. If that is not the case then the SQL operator approach can be used, with the optional third argument to `to_date()` to specify that it is expecting the string to be in English.

---

Your question seems to be partly confused by thinking that Oracle stores dates with a specific format. It does not; it uses an internal representation which you generally don't need to know about, and it's up to your client to display that internal value in a readable format, which is does using explicit or implicit conversions. You seem to be assuming dates are 'stored' as YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS, but that is just how your client is displaying the data to you.

Comment: What if you have a DD/MM/YY format? TO_DATE(:FIELD, 'DD/MM/YY') keep saying ORA-01821: date format not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Use the full format mask:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE( '2 Apr 2015 12:00 AM', 'DD MON YYYY HH12:MI AM'),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi in addition that i am using above format in sqlldr and am getting below error.ora-01821 date format not recognized. LAST_UPDATE DATE 'TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:LAST_UPDATE, 'DD MON YYYY HH12:MI AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')',